# Where does red highlighting come from with syntax off and spell on in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

`nvim -v` output:

```
NVIM 0.2.0-dev
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
Compilation: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wconversion -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -O2 -g -DDISABLE_LOG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/build/config -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/src -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/.deps/usr/include -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/.deps/usr/include -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/.deps/usr/include -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/.deps/usr/include -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/.deps/usr/include -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/.deps/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/neovim-gNtBZg/neovim-0.1.7ubuntu1+git201702111847+3127+23~ubuntu16.04.1/build/include
Compiled by root@lgw01-10

Optional features included (+) or not (-): +acl   +iconv    +jemalloc +tui      
For differences from Vim, see :help vim-differences

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"
```

- System: Ubuntu 16.04
- Terminal: GNOME Terminal 3.18.3
- `$TERM`: screen-256color

When syntax is off and spell is on only misspelled and rare words should be highlighted. Some keywords highlight but in different way than misspelled words.

I did **not** test it Vim.

Steps to reproduce using `nvim -u NORC` (without configuration file):

```
:syntax off
:set spell
```

Photo:

[image: wrong highlight]

Why is `function`, `let` higlighted blue? **Can I turn it off so only misspelled words will be highlighted** (no matter what type)?

Answer (score 1):

It's because syntax is required to recognize syntax-specific keywords.  Without syntax enabled, Vim has no idea if the text has special meaning or if you're just bad at spelling.

From `:h spell-syntax`

```
Files that use syntax highlighting can specify where spell checking should be
done:

1.  everywhere             default
2.  in specific items          use "contains=@Spell"
3.  everywhere but specific items  use "contains=@NoSpell"

For the second method adding the @NoSpell cluster will disable spell checking
again.  This can be used, for example, to add @Spell to the comments of a
program, and add @NoSpell for items that shouldn't be checked.
Also see |:syn-spell| for text that is not in a syntax item.
```

From `:h :syn-spell`

```
:sy[ntax] spell [toplevel | notoplevel | default]
  This defines where spell checking is to be done for text that is not
  in a syntax item:

  toplevel: Text is spell checked.
  notoplevel:   Text is not spell checked.
  default:  When there is a @Spell cluster no spell checking.

  For text in syntax items use the @Spell and @NoSpell clusters
  |spell-syntax|.  When there is no @Spell and no @NoSpell cluster then
  spell checking is done for "default" and "toplevel".

  To activate spell checking the 'spell' option must be set.
```

For the `vim` filetype, you can see strings and comments explicitly have `contains=@Spell` in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/vim.vim`.

Comment: Is it possible to turn red (or whatever color) highlight off? I just want nvim to be stupid and check for misspelled words (even if they are keywords).

Comment: How would you know if the word is misspelled without the highlight? If you're talking about changing the colors, see `:h :highlight` and `:h hl-SpellBad`.

Comment: The word `function` is not misspelled, yet it highlights.

Comment: Then you're talking about the *blue* highlight, which is `SpellRare`.  Read `:h hl-SpellRare`, `:h spell-RARE`, and `:h spell-affix-flags`.  This is all spelled out in `:h spell`. You should read it since further responses from me will just be citing the docs.